# Want to change the children font size using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, font-size

I having parent div tag and many child tag.. Each and every child tag's font-size is different.  While clicking a button every child element's font size should be increased with 1px of that tag's font-size.....

My try is:

```
       <html>
       <head>
        <style>
          .descendants *
          {
              display: block;
            border: 2px solid lightgrey;
            color: lightgrey;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 15px;
        }
       </style>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
      <script src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".baster").click(function () {
                //       var mas;
                //        for  mas in $(".descendants").children() 
                //        {
                //            var fontsize= parseInt($(".descendants").children().css("font-   size"));
                //         }
                ////            alert(fontsize);    
                ////            fontSize = fontSize + 1 + "px";
                //            $(".descendants").children().css({ "font-size": "font-size"+10      });
                //            $(".descendants").css({ "font-size": "font-size"+10 });
                //            $(".descendants").children().each(function () {
                $('.descendants *').css('font-size', '+=1px');
                //                var size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
                //                $(this).css("font-size", size + 1 + "pt");
                //                var size1 = parseInt($(this).children().css("font-size"));
                //                $(this).children().css("font-size", size1 + 1 + "pt");

                //                var myclass = jQuery('.myclass');


            });

            //            var size1 = parseInt($(".descendants").css("font-size"));
            //            $(".descendants").css("font-size", size1 + 1 + "pt");
            //             $(".descendants").children(this).css("font-size", size + 1 +  "pt");
        });
        //    });

    </script>

     </head>
     <body>
     <form runat="server">
     <div class="descendants" style="width: 500px; font-size: 20px;">
        div (current element)
        <div>
            p (child)
            <div style="font-size: 40px;">
                span (grandchild)</div>
            <div>
                p (child)
                <div style="font-size: 20px;">
                    span (grandchild)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <input id="Button1" type="button" class="baster" value="click" runat="server">
     </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$('#parent *').css('font-size','+=1px');
```

Comment: You are using .baster click function two times remove last one.

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript function will do what you need.

I have updated this again to correctly target all child elements.

This will work with inline styles also.

```
$('.descendants').find('*').click(function () {
    increaseSize();
});

function increaseSize() {
    $('.descendants').find('*').each(function () {
        $(this).css({
            'font-size': parseFloat($(this).css('font-size')) + 1
        });
    });
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zqD5/4/) example

Comment: i need to increase the font-size of all child element in each single click of button..

Comment: I have edited the code and jsfiddle example. It will now grow all child elements of the parent div

Comment: Great work but in my scenario, some child element having inline style font-size.  So this is not working for the elements, which are having inline font-size..

Comment: @user3373828 I have updated the answer. This code will work with inline styles also.

Comment: @user3373828 is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?